# How to edit or update wordpress custom database table from frontend?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new on wordpress, I have created a form in wordpress frontend user.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24hle.jpg)

I pasted my code below which I am using for submitting data in database.

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnsbmt'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $data_array = array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'], 
        'email' => $_POST['email'], 
        'adrs' => $_POST['adrs'], 
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'], 
        'subject' => $_POST['subject'], 
    );

    $table_name = 'pform';

    $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array, $formate=NULL);

    if($result == 1){
        echo "<h2>Form has been submitted</h2>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<h2>Something went wrong</h2>";
    }
}
```

how to edit or update this from frontend?

Comment: What is your problem ? What have you tried so far to fix it ?

Comment: i want to update or edit form, from frontend.

Comment: I've understood that but It's not an issue it's a feature request. If you don't have a problem your question doesn't belong to SO

Comment: i don't know how to write query for update or edit the form

Comment: could you please help me?

Comment: You have to read wordpress/php documentation

Comment: could you please send me any reference link

Comment: you have to create a template like user-dashboard

Comment: but i don't want to give any access of dashboard to user.

Comment: but i understood what you are asking but its better to simple use update query.

Comment: otherwise you can use cookies

Comment: You are almost done, just use your form to populate the $_POST parameters of an AJAX request. WordPress has a framework for handling AJAX requests that makes this very easy.